# Word VBA - Is changing the Viewing menu dropdown options via VBA possible?

Tags: vba, ms-word

We had a macro that has been working fine for years, but after a recent update, it stopped working, unless we perform a manual work around.

The issue relates to the Viewing menu, where the user can select Viewing, Reviewing or Allow Editing modes from the dropdown. Until recently, this worked in Viewing mode, however now we are having to get users to manually switch to Editing mode before running the package.

Just to avoid any confusion, it's this menu in the top right hand corner of Word:

[image]

The document defaults to Viewing on loading, and we've worked around that by getting users to manually change it to "Editing", but that's not an ideal solution.

I've tried a few suggestions, but so far nothing has worked. Is there a way to do this programatically in VBA?

I've tried the following to try and change the status of the dropdown, with no luck so far:

`ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False` - This was the first thing suggested, which relates to the view menu, so not what I'm after

`Application.CommandBars("Reviewing").Controls("Allow Editing").Execute` - Sounded a bit more like it, but gives "Invalid procedure call or argument" error

`Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1725).Execute` - Gave an "Object variable With block variable not set error"

`Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "ReviewPaneEditingView"` - Gave "Invalid procedure call or argument" error

I even tried a Sendkeys for Alt+V then E, but that didn't have any effect either (nor did the shortcut when I tried it manually)